# Аналоги File System Access API для работы с файлами на телефоне

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Мне нужно менеджерить файлы из PWA-приложения на разных устройствах.

Для ПК я использовала [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), но на телефонах это не работает.

---

Есть ли аналоговые АПИ для работы с файлами из PWA на телефоне?

Спасибо

Comment: react-native-fs смотрели?

Comment: Я на ReactJS пишу. Чтобы в браузере работать. А та либа для React Native

Comment: на данный момент этот API позволяет работать только на chromuim-браузерах и только на десктопе. рассмотрите возможность перевода своего приложения на react native